# kivyMD - create widgets dynamically from lists of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm quite new to kivyMD and I try to build simple Carousel with picture, icon and some text.

I wish to do this dynamic using 2 list of values - picture and name.

Here is how looks manual kv

```
Carousel:
    id: train_carousel
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDCard:
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.7
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.65}
            AsyncImage:
                source: "https://www.smth.com/img.png"
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "train"
            user_font_size: "40sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.2, "center_y": 0.2}
        MDLabel:
            text: "Thomas the Tank Engine"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": 0.2}
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDCard:
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.7
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.65}
            AsyncImage:
                source: "https://www.smth.com/img.png"
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "train"
            user_font_size: "40sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.2, "center_y": 0.2}
        MDLabel:
            text: "Thomas the Tank Engine"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": 0.2}
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDCard:
```

and this is my python file.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDIcon, MDLabel

Window.size = (400, 500)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_start(self, *args):

        list_of_names = ["Thomas", "Percy", "James", "Rebecca"]
        list_of_pics = ["https://www.smth.com/img1.png", "https://www.smth.com/img2.png", "https://www.smth.com/img3.png", "https://www.smth.com/img4.png"]

        counter = 0
        while counter < len(list_of_names):
            tmp_name = list_of_names[counter]
            tmp_pic = list_of_pics[counter]
            counter += 1
            print(counter)
            self.train_builder(tmp_pic, tmp_name)

    def train_builder(self, name, pic):
        card = MDFloatLayout()
        card.add_widget(MDCard(icon="train"))
        card.add_widget(MDIconButton(icon="train"))
        # card.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=pic))
        card.add_widget(MDLabel(text=name))
        self.root.ids.train_carousel.add_widget(card)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


MainApp().run()
```

I comment out AsyncImage as I know this is not proper way to do this, but still I cannot make this work at all.

Picture links in list are just for sample, not true images.

Also, lists are much longer that this sample. They have round 100 entries each.

Can someone help me with this :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find answer on my question , so here it is if someone struggles with similar issue.

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        carousel = Carousel()

        df = pd.read_excel("trains.xlsx")
        list_of_names = df['Name']
        list_of_pics = df['Pic']
        list_of_links = df['Link']

        tmp_counter = 0
        # while tmp_counter < len(list_of_names):
        while tmp_counter < 10:
            train_name = list_of_names[tmp_counter]
            train_pic = list_of_pics[tmp_counter]
            train_link = list_of_links[tmp_counter]

            md_float_layout = MDFloatLayout()
            md_card = MDCard(size_hint=(0.95, 0.8), pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.60})
            md_card.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=train_pic, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=True))

            md_float_layout.add_widget(md_card)
            md_float_layout.add_widget(MDIconButton(icon="train", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.08}))
            md_float_layout.add_widget(MDLabel(text=train_name, halign="center", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.9}, theme_text_color="Primary", font_style="H5"))
            md_float_layout.add_widget(MDLabel(text=train_link, halign="center", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.15}, theme_text_color="Primary", font_style="Body1"))
            # md_float_layout.add_widget(MDRaisedButton(text="Click to hear my name", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.15}, theme_text_color="Primary"))

            carousel.add_widget(md_float_layout)

            tmp_counter += 1

        return carousel


MainApp().run()
```

Enjoy :)